# QML: Refresh issue while receivinig C++ signals passed from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Hi i have bee playing recently with Qt for mobile development. I started simple using all the code in C++ (given that I have more experience with it) and now I'm starting to use QML. In my app I have a QQuickWidget in the ui where I display a map. The goal is simple to center the map every time the phone emits the coordinates.
This is how I set up my QML

```
ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/geom_map.qml"));
```

and this is my QML file

```
Rectangle {
width: 300
height: 300
visible: true


Plugin {
    id: osmPlugin
    name: "esri"
    // specify plugin parameters if necessary
    // PluginParameter {
    //     name:
    //     value:
    // }
}


Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: osmPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(51.0, -114.0) 
    zoomLevel: 10
    activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[1] // This selects the type of map to display



}
```

I declared a class to handle the sending of the coordinates to the QML and setup a connection on the QML for receiving the signal

```
    #ifndef COORDUPDATE_H
#define COORDUPDATE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVariant>

class coordUpdate : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit coordUpdate(QObject *parent = nullptr);
//    Q_INVOKABLE void sendupd(double xcoord, double ycoord);
private:


signals:
    void sendCoord(QVariant xcoord,QVariant ycoord);


private slots:



public slots:
    void sendupd(double xcoord, double ycoord);




};

#endif // COORDUPDATE_H


#include "coordupdate.h"
#include <QDebug>

coordUpdate::coordUpdate(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

}



void coordUpdate::sendupd(double xcoord,double ycoord){

    emit sendCoord(xcoord,ycoord);
    qDebug() << "signal emitted";
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if I call

```
void MainWindow::setGPSLocation(QGeoPositionInfo geoPositionInfo)
{

    statusBar()->showMessage("Updating position...",1000);
    QString text="Location=unknown";

    if (geoPositionInfo.isValid())
    {
        // get the current location coordinates
        QGeoCoordinate geoCoordinate = geoPositionInfo.coordinate();

        // transform coordinates to lat/lon
        qreal latitude = geoCoordinate.latitude();
        qreal longitude = geoCoordinate.longitude();
        qreal altitude = geoCoordinate.altitude();
        double lon = longitude;
        double lat = latitude;


        //on position updated we also need to record the data




    coordUpdate upd;
    ui->quickWidget->rootContext()->setContextProperty("updcoord",&upd);
    ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/geom_map.qml"));
    upd.sendupd(longitude,latitude);
    qDebug() << "reading coordinates" << longitude << latitude;


    }

}
```

Then the coordinates get updated but the whole thing gets refreshed. Is there a better way to update the information sent to the QML file? I know I would better developing in QML exclusively but I very interested in the use of QQuickWiget for the time being.

I'm not asking how to connect a signal from C++ to QML. The code does that. What I was asking was how to properly update the map with the information passed. I already read the documentation. Unfortunately not much of the documentation focus on QQuickWidgets but rather have a main class instantiated with QQmlEngine.

Comment: You can expose specific C++ properties to QML using Q_PROPERTY.
[Exposing Attributes of C++ Types to QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really don't know much about Q_PROPERTY. The property I want to modify is of a type QtPositioning.coordinate. I would have to redefine that on C++ side. I'm really not an expert and the examples in the link are not very useful. I am after all exposing the signal emitted as a property which does get updated in the QML. I can confirm the signal is being detected but the map not being updated. I don't know maybe a different example would be more useful.

Comment: I'm not asking how to make a connection from C++ to QML but rather how to handle the parameters passed in my particular case. @eyllanesc if you have nothing to add and you did not read the code posted or all the way then please let someone else help.

Comment: @eyllanesc you could have asked for clarification on the question if you did not understand it properly. Now based on your erroneous interpretation of the question when people that can potentially help will just pass because you improperly marked as such. This is why I do think it is a bad thing to do. Many people that come here for answers might not be professional developers but can find solutions in other examples and people suggesting edits to their codes.

Comment: @eyllanesc By the way I read the documentation extensively before posting a problem here. Sometimes the documentation might not work for a person. Might no be clear to a person with a different background for example. If you really want to help instead of marking duplicates you could have looked at the problem from your perspective and suggest something.

Comment: @eyllanesc So telling me to do an investigation is you idea of a full glass? You explicitly said and I quote "This question was asked innumerable times" you clearly misunderstood the question then because the signal is implemented correctly in the code. Keep marking duplicates it is easier in the end.

Comment: @eyllanesc From your perspective you were wrong and you are not even capable of admitting it.

Comment: Well, it seems we're not going to understand each other, bye :D Anyway, if I see something bad I'll notice, do not take it personel, [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Remember, it is ok to be wrong otherwise how will you learn! Don't erase your comments there is feedback there as well. All feedback is useful! :D #benice

Answer (score 0):

As described here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html, you have basically three ways to integrate C++ with QML code :

1. Expose your C++ class to QML ( properties, signals, slots..) and register it as an instanciable QML type
2. Same as 1 but register it as a singleton type so it is instantiated by the QML engine, not explicitly in the QML code
3. Same as 1 but make it available to QML via context properties for example, in this case, you create the instance of your class on the C++ side of your application

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by moving the Connections inside the Map and redefining in the mainwindow.cpp and mainwindow.h the way the QML is instantiated. That way the map is refreshed properly every time the QML captures the signal.

Added to mainwindow.cpp

```
private:
coordUpdate *upd;
```

Changed

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->startU->setDisabled(true);
    setupLogging();
    setupGPS();

    coordUpdate upd;
    ui->quickWidget->rootContext()->setContextProperty("updcoord",upd);
    ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/geom_map.qml"));


}
```

to

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->startU->setDisabled(true);
    setupLogging();
    setupGPS();

    upd = new coordUpdate;
    ui->quickWidget->rootContext()->setContextProperty("updcoord",upd);
    ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/geom_map.qml"));


}
```

and in the QML

```
Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true



    Plugin {
        id: osmPlugin
        name: "esri"

    }


    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmPlugin
//        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(y, x)
        zoomLevel: 15
        activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[1] // This selects thetype of mapa to display

        MapCircle {
            id:circle
            center: QtPositioning.coordinate(y, x) 
            radius: 50
            color: 'red'

        }

        // Create connections with c++
        Connections             // Define actions for custom slots
        {
            id:cppConnection
            target: updcoord
            onSendCoord: {
                  // To access signal parameter, name the parameter
                console.log("signal received",ycoord,xcoord)
                circle.center = QtPositioning.coordinate(ycoord,xcoord)


           }
        }

    }
}
```